# How do I ensure my twitter bootstrap theme fits for all devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am designing new website [Jopixels](http://jobpixels.com) to provide free themes for Twitter Bootstrap.
Bootsrap provides support for responsive deign. But in my themes I need to write my theme specific CSS that I need to ensure that it fits for all kind of devices.

I can not buy a Tablet or Smartphone to check test my design.

What is the correct way to ensure my designs are cross device compatible without real devices?

Comment: checkout this http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/ and http://viewportresizer.com/. Those are really nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bootstrap-specific, but are you aware of

http://tablet-emulator.org/

http://ipadpeek.com/

and

http://www.mobilewebsites4u.com/tester/index.htm

?? (the last one is really usefull for smartphones)

Answer (score 0):

You can also re-size your browser.
Twitter-bootstrap's response layout works on percentages and it is not using js for fluidity,so browser resizing will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is go to a website that has a "View Demo" for bootstrap theme.  View the source and use their code:

Look at this demo with device selector menu at bottom:

[Bootstrap Theme Demo](https://webthemez.com/preview/?bluesea-corporate-bootstrap-html-website-template#)

Now right click and view source (or add **view-source:url** if using Chrome):

Grab all the javascript and tweak it for your site.